# Autoplaynig video/image gallery - with a catch

Tags: jquery, video, image, gallery

Looking for a (jQuery) video/image gallery to implement on my website, I've found many freely available option. 
However, I need one that, when in "autoplay" mode and gets to a video file, automatically plays an **entire file**, and only then moves on to the next image/video. Similar to what **Picasaweb** are doing when you ask to autoplay an online gallery of your images/videos.

I have found, for example, this plugin: http://www.yoxigen.com/yoxview/. Notice that images 6 and 8 are actually video feeds, but when in autoplay mode, are treated just like any other image, i.e. - displayed for a few seconds then moves on to the next file... not what I need.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether it fulfills your exact requirement (i.e. whether the feature can be combined with an `autoplay` setting), but [JWPlayer](http://www.longtailvideo.com/) supports [XML playlists](http://developer.longtailvideo.com/trac/wiki/Player5Formats#Playlists). You'd have to check out whether it works for you.

It's not free for commercial and CMS-driven sites, though. Licenses start at €69.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Pekka. I'll review the JWPlayer.